# MVC reporting different port number when I check Request.Url.ToString() using Azure emulator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I start off on the following web page:

```
http://127.0.0.1:84/Administration/Accounts/Home
```

I then select a link and it takes me to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:84/Administration/Accounts/ShowSummary?ds=0001
```

At the start of the ShowSummary razor page I check the

```
Request.Url              http://127.0.0.1:86/Administration/Accounts/ShowSummary?ds=0001}
Request.Url.Authority   "127.0.0.1:86"
Request.UrlReferrer - {http://127.0.0.1:84/Administration/Accounts/Home}
```

Every time I try this it always reports the port 86 and not port 84. This is important to me as I store the URL. Does anyone have an idea why it shows a different port? The correct port should be 84 but Url and Url.Authority report 86

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I have pretty good idea why this is happening. First please let me share a detail on Windows Azure, so you will be able to understand the nature of the issue you have.

When you deploy your cloud service in Windows Azure environment it lives in a Virtual Machine (so called Instance) behind a Load Balancer (or LB). When you define an [Input Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433020.aspx), you instruct the Windows Azure infrastructure that you want a specific TCP port to be routed to your Instance. So, the LB opens on its firewall port 80, and routes the traffic from that port to your VM. A port 80 on your VM is also opened in the Firewall. However there are 2 distinguished hosts - the LB and the VM, where you can have port 80 on both.

In order to correctly simulate all that behaviour locally, Windows Azure Emulator creates a Web Site in your local IIS and binds it to some port (86 in your case!). Then it "simulates" the LB and opens port 84 (for the simulated LB). This is so, because you may have more than one instances defined in your role. The local emulator creates a separate website for each and any instance you have defined. And each instance will have its own designated port (86,87,88 etc..), while the original (in your case 84) will be only one - for the simulated LB.

That's why your Request.Url.Authority is port 86 - because your local site is bound to port 86. And that's why the URLReferer is port 84 - becase the actual request comes from the simulated Load Balancer which works on port 84.

I hope you are guess that this will not happen in real Azure environment, because both ports will be 80.

When people deal with port I usually advise to use the IPEndpoint instance which can be obtained from:

```
RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["HttpIn"].IPEndpoint
```

But your case is a bit different. You are logging the full URL. I don't know what r u trying to achieve, but here are some hints, you may consider being valuable:

- Try disecting the URL and change the port using the IPEndpoint
  instance
- Log just the path, not the full URL (skip the address & port
  parts)

Hope this helps.

Comment: No idea why this is selected as the correct answer; `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["HttpIn"].IPEndpoint` returns `{127.255.0.2:82}` and not `127.0.0.1:81` which ould be correct in my developer environment, I think @Loki has the correct solution below.

Comment: because things change between 2011 and 2014 ... Original answer is from Dec. 2011, while Loki"s is from March 2014 ...  Azure changes with weeks. I cannot keep looking back and update all the answers I have ever provided. And is accepted because it was working by the time of asking and answering.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen is correct that Loki's answer is the correct one as of 2014, but this answer still has an excellent explanation of how Azure sets up its environment locally.

Answer (score 3):

If some still needs to get absolute Uri while working in the local Azure environment the solution is:

```
var absoluteUriString = string.Format(
   "{0}://{1}{2}",
   Request.Url.Scheme,      // protocol
   Request.Headers["Host"], // needed host with correct port number
   Request.RawUrl);         // right part of the uri string
var absoluteUri = new Uri(absoluteUriString);
```

Comment: As of 2014 this is the correct answer to the question as `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["HttpIn"].IPEndpoint` does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You know how when you restart your web site too quickly after closing the previous session, then it will allocate you the next port number?  84 -> 85 -> 86

In this situation I have sometimes observed old port numbers continuing to work, even though their debugging sessions has stopped.  I have never really looked into it, and perhaps it is just a brain fault on my part, but perhaps this is what is happening.  You could try port 86 directly, and see if that works.